# What self-defense weapons are legal in London?

Tags: uk, legal, safety, london, security

I've travelled  London many times, and this is the first time I got robbed in broad daylight, in afternoon! Around four  youth wearing masks brandished machetes, asked for my purse and everything in it. I surrendered. I was with my 5 y.o., and I didn't try to fight back.  I lost my handbag, iPhone, convertible 2 in 1 laptop, wallet, £500 cash.

I reported to police, but they said they couldn't do anything. I didn't get a good look of these criminals, and I'm leaving London in a few days. CCTV can't see through masks.

Comment: You could have the strongest chemical spray known to man and trying to use it against 4 guys with machetes would not be a smart move.

Comment: Not carrying 4k£ of valuables is probably a much better “defense” than any kind of self-defense weapon.

Comment: @ThePhoton Thanks, but I got that. I removed any reference to sprays in my question. I want to ask in general.

Comment: If you were in the US, and you had, let's just say, **ten**  handguns in your pockets, **and** you had, oh, let's say, an assault rifle, fully loaded, armed, cocked, safety off, and actually *in your hands, ready to use* ....... if you were attacked or confronted by four guys with machetes, you would not have the slightest, vaguest, chance of doing anything, at all. You did exactly the right thing.  it is utterly inconceivable you could "defend yourself!" using "weapons!" against four machete men.  Thank God, nothing bad happened.

Comment: Even with a gun, you'd be taking a big chance confronting 4 attackers with machetes. There isn't really any realistic way to defend yourself in that scenario, except give up your valuables, and hope their intention is really robbery and not murder.

Comment: Even in the US, where concealed carry is legal...  A friend told me of being robbed by two guys on bicycles riding around him, shouting at him, shoving guns in his face.  He gave up his wallet, etc.  He said that even if he'd had a gun, he couldn't have used it then.  He could've used it once the guys started cycling away...but then he was no longer in danger of his life, so he might've gone to jail for it.

Comment: I've re written this to broaden the question, not just about the robbery committed on me.

Comment: @TamaraMilanovic *broadening* the question is a rather strange thing to do to a question that was closed for lacking focus.

Comment: In the UK, your best bet is probably going to be a rape alarm. They're very loud and unpleasant. AFAIK they're legal they can disorient an attacker and they'll get the attention of anyone nearby

Comment: The problem with weapons, kind of similar to what @Fattie has said, is best case scenario you end up in the same state as Jonathan Mok (pictures in OP's question), worst case is either this provokes the attackers/makes them even more mad (i.e. "ah you want to fight us with weapons, well now we're going to use the full force of my 3 mates here"), or it's also not inconceivable to think of a scenario the attackers take your spray/knife/gun/whatever and use it against you. As sad as it is, having a self-defense weapon might make things even worse... [continued below]

Comment: ... As sad as it is, having a self-defence weapon might make things even worse UNLESS you train with that weapon on a weekly/daily basis or regularly do any other generic self-defence training course, so that you're reactions are fast to be able to use the weapon and prevent the attackers taking it away from you. Which is not really suitable as a generic advice to your generic population.

Comment: That's probably the most radical edit I've seen around here, especially for a question that was asked (and closed) 7 months ago...

Comment: Editor, just post that as an answer if you want.  SO is not available for long-form edits.

Comment: @Fattie I believe the question is locked/closed for answers? P.S. Just curious as even though I'm not the editor. 

Comment: @Fattie I'd like to keep this edition. Please don't roll back.

Comment: @TamaraMilanovic:  Your new version has a rather different focus than your original question, and makes the answers below rather nonsensical.  If you want to ask a new question, use the "New Question" button above instead.  (Also, be sure there's actually a question in your new version.)

Comment: hi @TamaraMilanovic (1) normally, yes, of course, naturally you should change edits you don't like - cheers  (2) unfortunately in this particular case (2a) basically, other people - even the original poster - simply can't make such ENORMOUS edits (2b) the new edit just had nothing at all to do with the original question, it's not viable. Nobody is gonna llow such an "edit".  (3) However as Many Have Said, please do go right ahead and post a new question, as long as you like !!!

Comment: @Fattie Thanks. I've tried to meet these comments in the middle by posting my question at the bottom.

Comment: A new roll back to the basic question, without the unneeded photos. Your edit changes it to a new question, that is not what this site it about. Ask a new question if you feel that your new version is needed. (The answer stays that you are not allowed 'self defense weapons'.)

Answer (score 21):

The link that you cite already states the law: Any “noxious substance” is illegal. So this is likely yucky stuff, but with no irritant. It may be disorienting for a moment, but I doubt it’ll incapacitate a determined attacker.

For practical advice: Don’t. Even if you were a trained officer, going against 4 armed attackers (or even 2) with just a can of pepper spray would be a recipe for disaster. To put it bluntly: You don’t want to anger a person with a knife if you can avoid it.

If you want to feel safer, I’d suggest you look for a reputable self defence class. I assume that there they can teach you how to escape or incapacitate someone if you can’t avoid the confrontation (also, if the spray is any good they’ll probably teach you how to actually use it).

**Addition:** This answer was to specifically address the legality of pepper spray substitutes (which was the gist of the original question). There is already a great answer on defensive weapons in general, so I'm not going to add to that.

Also, I *did not* want to suggest that self-defence training would have made a difference in your situation. **No type of weapon or training would have**.

You may happen to have everyday objects (e.g. an umbrella) that can be of some help against an assailant, even if not in that particular situation.

Comment: Also in a self defence class they won't tell you anything else but to surrender (or run away, if possible) to four guys with knifes…

Comment: Thanks, but I got that. I removed any reference to sprays in my question. I want to ask in general.

Answer (score 11):

Carrying pepper spray around may get you into trouble with the law, it is probably illegal despite what vendors may tell you.

---

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-defence_in_English_law

> Self-defence in English law is a complete defence to all non-sexual offences involving the unlawful use of force (i.e. anything from battery to murder). In other words, it results in a charge if a death occurs because minimal force was not used. Generally speaking, the rationale is that the defendant is not guilty of the offence if murder doesn't occur.

and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offensive_weapon

> An offensive weapon is a tool made, adapted or intended for the purpose of inflicting mental or physical injury upon another person.

...

> Under England/Wales' Prevention of Crime Act 1953, Section 1(1) states it is an offence to carry an offensive weapon on or about the person while in a public place

So far as I can tell, pepper spray is normally considered an offensive weapon.

---

In [Are there any legal self defence products that I can buy?](https://www.askthe.police.uk/content/Q589.htm) The UK police say

> The only fully legal self defence product at the moment is a rape alarm.

...

> There are other self defence products which claim to be legal (e.g. non toxic sprays), however, until a test case is brought before the court, we cannot confirm their legality or endorse them. If you purchase one you must be aware that if you are stopped by the police and have it in your possession there is always a possibility that you will be arrested and detained until the product, its contents and legality can be verified.

...

> There are products which squirt a relatively safe, brightly coloured dye (as opposed to a pepper spray). A properly designed product of this nature, used in the way it is intended, should not be able to cause an injury. However, if injury does occur, this may be assault.

Comment: `you must be aware that if you are stopped by the police and have it in your possession there is always a possibility that you will be arrested and detained until the product, its contents and legality can be verified.` I was under the impression that stop and search is, on the whole, illegal in the UK.

Comment: Thanks, but I got that. I removed any reference to sprays in my question. I want to ask in general.

Comment: @FinnO'leary [No, it's legal](https://www.gov.uk/police-powers-to-stop-and-search-your-rights) but the grounds are quite tightly drawn. However, a police officer may see the weapon (as it has to be easily to hand) and at that point you don't need to be searched, or there definitely is a specific thing to search for.

Comment: Related: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/39501/could-the-police-be-sued-for-failing-to-protect-citizens-in-countries-where-gun

Answer (score 11):

If you carry *anything* with the *intention* of using it against an assailant, it is a weapon. Even walking with your house keys in your hand with a key protruding from your fist.

Comment: How does this answer my question? This is pretty obvious. House keys can't usually serve as self-defense weapons.

Comment: Keys have often been used as weapons.

Comment: Keys can easily be used as self defence weapons (Or offensive weapons). Football hooligans used to punch each other with Keys protruding from their fist as @Owain mentioned above

Comment: @TamaraMilanovic it answers the question, as any weapon is illegal and anything carried with the purpose to be used as a weapon is considered a weapon. Therefore anything you carry that you are carrying for the sole or main purpose of self defense is classed as a weapon and therefore illegal.